# Android Cucumber report generating duplicate Features

Tags: android, cucumber, report

I am using cucumber in android for BDD tests but in report generation features are displaying twice.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve the problem? I am facing the same.

Comment: Yes, had to update cucumber version

Comment: Indeed, using the newer version (4.9.1) solved the problem of duplicated results. It was a fix related to JUnitFormatter.